# Html submit button. If form option selected Jquery Alert to confirm

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui, select

I have a basic html form.  The form is processed with PHP upon submission.

I have a unique condition where is a select value is (for arguments sake)  value = '2' then data is migrated from one DB to another.  This is a 'one time only option, and confines the data in the rest of the form into an uneditable state.

As a result I wish to detect that the selection value is '2' and then pop up the alert saying 'are you sure' with confirm Y/N options.

Clearly upon Yes the form will then pass to PHP processor, and upon No nop action would be taken.

Can anyone guide me as to where I'd start as JS and JQuery are sadly not my forte.

Many Thanks in advance

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're going to use a radio button to define the different values to be selected.

Set up your radio input and have a unique name. For you jquery you need to hook the "Change" event of that radio.

```
$('input[name="rdoDB"]').change(function () {
    if($(this).val() == 2){
        CallMyPopup();
    }
});
```

Now for the form submit event you don't want to submit the form when your value is 2.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    if($('input[name="rdoDb"]').val() == 2)
    {
        CallMyPopup();
        return false //stop form propagation;
    }
});
```

I should point out to be secure you need to do a backend check in php to make sure that you aren't evaluating on the disabled data when this value is 2.

The [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) website is a great place to get familiar with jQuery.